# Query json array inside SELECT statement, for parameters in function such as Point

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example data in each point.

```
{
  "city": "Fredrikstad",
  "country": "NO",
  "isRough": true,
  "latLong": [
    59.2198,
    10.9247
  ],
  "longName": "NO",
  "timezone": "Europe/Oslo",
  "shortName": "Fredrikstad"
}
```

The query I attempted, but failed and can't find answers for.

```
SELECT *, point(59.9260437, 10.7221398) <@> (point( (location -> latLong[0]),  (location -> latLong[1]) )::point) as distance
FROM myapp.recipes
ORDER BY distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to some magic casting to make it work.

Working example.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    point(59.9260437, 10.7221398) <@> point( ((recipes.location -> 'latLong' -> 0)::FLOAT), ((recipes.location -> 'latLong' -> 1)::FLOAT) )::point as distance
FROM myapp.recipes
ORDER BY distance;
```